# How do I access the state of individual bits of a word in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

I'm writing a program and I need to determine if bits 3 and 6 are set.  I know that I can rotate a word or left/right shift it.

But how do I access individual bit's state?  Do I use a bitwise operator like and/xor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do a bitwise and with 0x08 and 0x40 (presuming bit 0 is the lowest order bit).  You would use the andi instruction to do this.

If $t0 is the value you want to test:

```
andi $t1, $t0, 0x08
andi $t2, $t0, 0x40
```

$t1 will be non-zero if bit 3 is set, $t2 will be non-zero if bit 6 is set.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, bitwise operators are what you use.  You can AND with a bitmask that has only bits 3 and 6 set.  Then do a comparison to zero.

something like (I haven't done assembler in a long time):

```
and     r2, r1, 0x48  # r2 = r1 & 0x48
cmp     r2, 0x48
jz     zzzzzz   #jmp to zzzzz if bits 6 and 3 are set
```

Comment: I don't do mips, but won't that jump if bits 3 *or* 6 are set?

Comment: You're right.  I was being sloppy.  It should be a comparison to 0x48 and then jz instead of jnz.

Comment: Is it proper for me to edit my answer to fix the problem after people have commented on it?

Answer (score 2):

One technique for testing a single bit in MIPS assembly is to shift the desired bit into the most-significant bit position and use bltz/bgez to test the state of the bit. This saves an instruction in cases where the andi instruction can't be used to select the desired bit.