# Get values of specific bits in a byte

Tags: assembly, binary, mips

For example, I have this binary number: 
00100101
And I want to make a new number with only the last 2 bits and the others 0, like so:
00000001

I am working with MIPS so I assume I must use some combination of logical or, xor, and, ect but unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the state of individual bits of a word in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750013/how-do-i-access-the-state-of-individual-bits-of-a-word-in-mips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old, but it is the top of the search results as the top hit.  I don't think it will hurt to explain why in some detail.

## Quick and dirty answer after the heading below

To get specific bits, one way to do it is by a "bitmask".  A bitmask says that you are only going to let certain bits through.  Just like when you mask something to paint.

logical AND is the instruction we want.  Logical operations compare individual bits. Its the central operation of anything digital- anything that operates like a computer.  When you get all the way down, all any chip is doing is comparing single bits in new and creative ways.  There are 2 operations and 2 modifiers giving AND, OR, NOR, XOR, NAND, NOT, XNOR.

I threw a summary on Logical Comparators at the end.  Review it if needed. 
`(in retrospect, I think this is the most valuable part for a newbie.)`

But if we set one bit to be what we want, then on the other side well get what we want.  Say I want bits 2, 3, 4, and 7.  7- Y N N Y Y Y N N - 0 right.  Well, then I create a mask with 1's there.  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 and do logical AND.

So then it's just simple math.  The computer speaks binary.  I just give it the number that 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 corresponds to.

Counting in binary.  Far right = 1, and then we double in each position.  We also start counting at 0.  So the 0th bit on the right = 1, the first bit is 2, the 3rd =4, then 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.  Play with this if you want, but using this number you can get any value from 0 to 255.  (or 127 to -128) but the negatives are more complicated.  Might be relevant though.

It's important to note that there are two types of integers in a computer language- **Signed**, and **Unsigned**. That last bit- the 7th bit (which is the 8th bit to your or I, is worth 128 an unsigned int, but it's just equal to the sign in the signed int.  Surprisingly, they both have the same number of digits (or maybe not surprisingly once you think about it)

As an example, lets take the given number `[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]` and make the first bit a 1 `{1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0}`, If this is an unsigned integer, its worth 156 (`128 + 16+ 8+ 4)`, but if the 7th bit is a sign bit--  Calculating it is slightly complicated.  You must use (["Two's complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) to get the value of 1001110.  And while it has a fascinating history that is worth discussing, just not here.  The signed bit is calculated by flipping every bit- because in negative numbers- 0 now counts as 1's and 1's are 0's.  So lets take `{1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0}` and make it a format were used to- `{0 1 1 0  0 0 1 1}`, we just have to remember its negative. The value of it, flipping and add 1: `-1 + (64) + (32) + (2) + (1) = 99(-)` and then we must remember to subtract `-99 -  1 = -100`.

We subtract one because 0000 0000 is 0.  And if we called 1111 1111 = 0 then we would have 2 values for 0! (incidentally, this is called **One's Complement**).  So, the next number in line- -1!. I am sure there are better two's compliment discussions and its out the scope of this.

So you say,
Value AND 28 = newValue
then you can AND that.

or do a FOR loop

```
for x in [0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,-128]
    if (x AND value!= 0){
         y = log2(abs(x))
         print("the bit is a one in position" + y)
    } else {
        print("the bit is a 0 in position" + y)

    }
```

Or do a for loop using the power aspect to iterate through.

```
for(i = 1; i < 18, i++){
    byte y = 2 ** n
    if ((value & ubyte) == 0) { //is 0}
```

or this java example which is basically the same:

```
class BitDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bitmask = 0x000F;
        int val = 0x2222;
        // prints "2"
        System.out.println(val & bitmask);
    }
}
```

## Quick Answer is here

I've aimed to answer the question more generally for all programming languages since this is a 4 yr old question.  In **assembly**, you need to get more creative.  As you know, since youre asking, every operation has to be discrete.  Really forces you to think.

```
li $t1, 0x020    # get the sixth bit, HEX 20 = DEC 32  in binary = 0b0010 0000
and $t2, $a0, $t1  #t1 gets the bit
slt $t3, $zero, $t2  # compares zero < t2 and if true stores
                       #1 into t3, so stores the 6th bit in its own register.
```

use slt, it's a single op instruction, all the other comparators are pseudo instructions, which is less efficient.  It's more elegant.

You can also combine the first two instructions with the *psuedoinstruction* 
`**andi** $t2, $a0, 0x02` But the compiler will just convert it to the above in the background.  I guess save a register.

Another option, if you know the bit you are looking for is to shift until its bit 0.

`srl $v0, $t2, 5    # since we went after the 6th bit`

I don't like using andi (and immediete, but I can't remember why.  I got some weird behavior in the past, but the shortest way to solve the above:

```
 #your value = $a0
 andi $v0,  $a0,  0x01     #already in first bit, no more work
 andi $v1,  $a0,  0x02    
 slr  $v1,  $v1, 1         #since we have 1 bit in 2nd bit, just shift one
```

In your case, you want the last two bits, so we do 1 + 2 (the bit values)= 3.  That's where the answer above gets 0x03.  0x tells the assembler its hex bc the assembler only really likes hex.  Though it would take decimal 3 if its good (MARS).

---logical comparators review/intro---
I'm a smart dude I am told.  But when I started out all these were really confusing to me and hard to remember.  That was until I looked at it for a while and realize something.
It's actually really simple. Now I look at it and think, why was that ever hard.  It's easier than 1 + 1 in 1st grade.  So if you're reading this thinking why is this guy explaining, its because you don't remember the first time you saw it.

Think of it this way, and it's much easier there are only 2 choices, 2 operations to remember and they're super easy to remember-  *AND* and *OR* (or neither) for logical comparisons.  They're not opposites, they're different, and they do what they say. Then there are 2 modifiers.  That's it.  Understanding AND and OR are in the name, and knowing the adjectives is super easy.

- ***NOT*** the first one we talk about is the easiest.  It's a modifier, more than an operator- it only takes one value, so it's not a logical comparator like *OR* or *AND*.  It just does the opposite.  If it's 1, it says 0.  If it's 0, then it's 1.  Its opposite is nothing.  In a circuit, it would be a wire.  Nothing changes.  How does it work if it only takes 1 value, I think of it as coming after.  You do the *OR* or *AND* operation, then flip it.  So *AND* and *OR*:

*AND* and *OR* are simple,

- ***AND***- if both things are 1 (1 *AND* 1) then the value is one.  Nothing else is true here.  1 *AND* 0 is FALSE.  0 and 0 are FALSE.  You only get paid if you show up to work *AND* do the work.  The FALSE and FALSE wouldn't work in that statement.
- ***OR*** says that if either is 1 then the value is one.  That's all. Bring me the book back *OR* pay me $20 and I won't beat you up.  You can do one or the other.  What if you do both?  That's the important bit.  Well, you won't get beaten up so the value of 1 OR 1 is *TRUE*.  IF you don't bring the book or bring $20 then 'not getting beat up'= FALSE.
- ***X*****[...]**  Now that last part from the OR was the important part.  The 1 *OR* 1 = 1 bit, the scenario where you can bring $20 OR return the book.  So let's do a logical comparison to see what is a good idea.  Doing both is kinda dumb. That's where ***X*** comes in- the *X* is for e*X*clusive.  Seriously.  It gets rid of a special case in *OR* where *OR* is true if A or B is 1. X says, don't use the 1 / 1  = true option, I want exclusively 1 value true.  That is where a lot of people get confused, OR is *at least* one bit is true, ***XOR*** says *exactly*  1 bit is true.  So now 1 ***XOR*** 1 *is*(=) 0.

That's it from those you get all the options.

- ***NOT*** - it's not really a comparator, just inverts 1 input, but usually lumped in
- ***AND*** - both compared values are true, nothing else.
- ***NAND*** - inverted *AND*, so if both are true, then is false, everything else is true- (0,1)(0,0)(1,).
- ***OR*** - *At least one* is true  (1,0)(1,1)(0,1) = True, only (0,0) is false
- ***NOR***- Inverts OR, so from above, (1,0)(1,1)(0,1) = False, and (0,0) is true.
- ***XOR*** - Gets rid of the special (1,1) = true case in OR.  The X only works on *OR*, Says now exactly 1 is true.

  - ***XNOR*** - This one will make your head hurt.  But just do it stepwise with a truth table. We start with *OR*, and remove (1,1) = true, so when the bits match =  false, and when they are different its true (1,0)(0,1). then invert it.  So now, it's false when the bits differ (1,0)(0,1).  But it's true when they match. (1,1) and (0,0),  So this is an *AND* gate, and an inverted *AND* (***NAND***) gate joined by an *OR/XOR* gate. (The X is irrelevant, as you cant have both bits simultaneously be 1,1 and 0,0 unless we're talking quantum stuff.

Comment: Your example is wrong: `1 0 0 1 1 1 0` only has 7 bits, so its +78 unsiged, or signed 8-bit.  Or in 7-bit two's complement, it's `-50`.  You got your place values wrong when you flipped the bits; it would be `-(32+16+1) - 1`.  Or more simply, just treat the top bit as having a place value of `-64` instead of messing around with the 2's complement identity.  So `-64 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 0 = -50`.

Comment: With that correction, this looks like a decent article explaining bitwise operations.  I feel like this is a pretty obscure place to post it; what search terms is this a top hit for?  If you want to write up a full guide to bitwise ops, there's probably a more generic question you could post this under, and maybe link to it in a comment on this question.  Because this gets pretty far off topic for this specific question.  2's complement is totally irrelevant, and so are all the bitwise ops other than AND.

Comment: MIPS has 16-bit immediates (zero-extended for bitwise ops like `andi` and `ori`, sign-extended for `addi`/`addiu`).  You should just use `0x20` directly instead of wasting an `li` instruction on it.  To extract any contiguous bitfield of 16 bits or narrower, just `srl  $t0, $v1, low_bit`   / `andi $t0, $t0, (1<<(high_bit-low_bit))-1`.  A power of 2 minus one has all the bits set below that position,  e.g. `andi $t0, $t0, 0x7f`.  Shifting before ANDing avoids problems with bits outside the low 16.

Comment: *bc the assembler only really likes hex.*  I'd be surprised if there are any MIPS assemblers that don't accept decimal integer literals.  At worst you might find one that treated all numbers as hex, in which case `3` would still work but `0x3` would be better documentation.  (The crusty old DOS `debug.exe` apparently was/is like that, but it's (barely) an x86 assembler.)  Anyway, it's humans that like hex for bitmasks.  Compilers like gcc emit assembly with all numeric constants in decimal, which makes for pretty unreadable code when you compile something like `return foo & 0xff00`.

Comment: Yea I missed a character when I was typing fast. I’ll correct it when I’m back on desktop.

Comment: Honestly I probably would rather redo it sans the 8th but significant to avoid the signed unsigned - and twos complement discussion

Comment: Well the first pass read coverts the decimal values to hex for reading by the assember. So it depends. But yea, I mean, I guess I don’t disagree. That MARS at least will accept decimal values in the immediate fields.  Thanks for the feedback. I’ll try and make those corrections.

Comment: Huh?  Why would an assembler internally convert them to hex strings, instead of binary integers?  If I was writing an assembler, I'd just use `atoi` or `sscanf("%i"`) to get an `int`.

Comment: wow, this is a bit of surprise, that's a very detailed explanation there Peter, even 3 years later i appreciate the effort, cheers!

Comment: You wrote: *in negative numbers- 0 now counts as 1's and 1's are 0's*.  That's an odd way of thinking about it.  In 8-bit 2's complement, the sign bit has a place-value of `-128`, and the rest of the bits have the same place-values as unsigned.  So all-ones gives us `(-128) + 127 = -1`.  Using the 2's complement identity of `~x + 1` is a lot more complicated (and has a corner case for `-128`) if you just want to know the value, not actually negate something.

Answer (score 1):

You only need bitwise and for that. This will return you the first 2 bits in the byte.

In C: 
    int result = value & 0x03;

This will do, for example, 00100101 & 00000011, which is 00000001.

Comment: value & 0x2 will return the second bit in the byte. You need to do value & 0x3.

Answer (score 1):

The MIPS instruction to do this is `ANDI $t0, 0x3`

Comment: MIPS is a 3-operand ISA, so you'd want `ANDI $t1, $t0, 0x3`  (Or `ANDI $t0, $t0, 0x3` if you want to replace the input with the output.)

Comment: (MIPS assemblers usually accept instructions with 2 operands and convert them to the corresponding 3-operand form.)