# How can I define my own commands in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to define 4 own commands. Each of the command is recognisable by first two bits. Then I need to input these commands from .bin file. (something like turtle in LOGO language). What am I supposed to do?

I tried using
command: .word 0 0
to generate required words for these commands, but I don't know how to access it now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5WVq.png)

Comment: Since each command is recognizable by two bits, you'd need to apply `andi` on the first word of each command. Are you familiar with [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750013/how-do-i-access-the-state-of-individual-bits-of-a-word-in-mips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, I really understand your question.

But if you have your "commands" in a .word in MIPS asm, accessing them is easy.

```
cmd: .word  12345   #(or whatever)
     .text
     la $t0, cmd    # load adress of cmd in reg $t0
     lw $t1, 0($t0) # load data at @cmd in register $t1
```

and now the "command" is in register $t1 and you can do anything you want with it.

But the hard part is to program an interpreter for these "commands" in order to transform them to actions.
You can do that in MIPS asm, but it is not the easiest solution.
I would rather suggest using a higher level language (C, C++, py, etc).

Comment: I have an external file containing commands in form of 16bit words (e.g. 1100101000101111); commands are recognisable by last two bits e.g. 1..110 is set position, 1..100 is set direction etc. Then I need to open this file in MIPS, load these commands, and then program starts working on these commands. Finally program draws the result in the bmp file.

Comment: To summarize each bit of the command means something and I need to access those bits separately

Comment: Opening and reading a file in asm is system dependant and can be tricky. When writing the program, better use a table in the asm source. Then read the successive cmds in the table, analyse it by means of bitwise operations as pointed out by Ruud Helderman and update the bitmap.

Comment: So you mean I should create a table in asm and in each row load one cmd and then use bitwise operations to access individual bits?

Comment: To work out the program, it is the simplest way. Later, you can add the code to read a file into a table.